# Symfony2 security system implementation without Doctrine entities

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, entity

How can I have a security system for Symfony2 which is responsible for user authentification without Doctrine entities. So I need to use raw SQL queries to retrieve users from database. Further my User entity should not contain any Doctrine mapping.

[cookbook/security](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html) shows you how to load your users from the database via a Doctrine entity. But what I want is to load my users from the database without Doctrine entity.

Comment: Make own user provider. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html

Comment: @malcolm Thanks it is done!